# Operations with numbers

Tags: javascript, math, protractor

What kind of methods for working with integer and double numbers has protractor?

I need to use round() function, but I can't found it in API. Maybe somebody know where I can find it?

Also I have problems with convert text fields to number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Protractor doesn't have any specific methods for working with numbers, but you could retrieve the number via the Protractor .getText() (if it's stored in an input) and apply rounding and such via standard JS:

```
var nr = element(by.css('.number'));
nr.getText().then (function(value){   
      var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
      return Math.round(floatValue);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 5.2; 
number = Math.round(number); 
//return 5 
console.log(number);


var number = 5.7; 
number = Math.round(number); 
//return 6 
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Thank you! But where I can see all methods of Math library for protractor?

Comment: It is not really protractor stuff, it is plain JavaScript. You can find all available methods here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp